# Magento dropdown group selection customer registration

Tags: customer

I am trying to make a group selection dropdown on the Magento customer registration page work. I have done all of the following:

Inserted the following code into template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml:

```
<label for="group_id" style='margin-top:15px;'><?php echo $this->__('Which group do you belong to? (select "Pet Owner" if you are uncertain)') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div style='clear:both'><p style='color:red;'>Note: DVM/DACVO and Institution accounts require administrative approval.</p></div>
            <div class="input-box" style='margin-bottom:10px;'>
                    <select style='border:1px solid gray;' name="group_id" id="group_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Group') ?>" class="validate-group required-entry input-text" />
                        <?php $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray(); ?>
                        <?php foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
                            <?php if ($group['label']=="Pet Owner" || $group['label']=="DVM / DACVO" || $group['label']=="Institution"){?>
                                <option value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>"><?php print $group['label'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

Then the following in /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php in the createPostAction():

```
$customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'));
```

Finally the following in /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml where group id was added:

```
  <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <prefix>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <name>1</name>
                </prefix>
                <firstname>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <name>1</name>
                </firstname>
                <middlename>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <name>1</name>
                </middlename>
                <lastname>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <name>1</name>
                </lastname>
                <suffix>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <name>1</name>
                </suffix>
                <email>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </email>
                <password>
                    <create>1</create>
                </password>
                <confirmation>
                    <create>1</create>
                </confirmation>
                <dob>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </dob>
                <group_id><create>1</create><update>1</update></group_id>
                <taxvat>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </taxvat>
                <gender>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </gender>
            </customer_account>
```

I have tested it several times and every customer is still being added as the default customer group. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @vinai updated this module today - maybe check out the newest version https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

Comment: He only added some comments. And I have already modified his module to do what I want. I am having trouble now getting the 'Choose which group you belong to:' dropdown in the customer registration to post that data correctly. New accounts are just being added to the default customer group.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump` on `$this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id')` to see if it's returning something other than 1?

Comment: And can you paste the results of `var_dump($customer->getData());die();` in the AccountController.php?

Comment: I will try this in a couple hours.

Comment: Hey Phil, I  tried Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'), null, 'caitlin.log');
   Mage::log(var_dump($customer->getData());die()),null, 'caitlin.log'); in my accountcontroller file and its not even logging anything! (I wasn't sure whether or not to include the var_dump so I tried it one of them). See what I'm doing wrong? BTW let's be friends (my skype Caitlinhav)

Comment: PS I created an account to trigger the class and method

Comment: Pinging @philwinkle - you'll be pissed when you see the answer :-)

Comment: @benmarks (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller class definitions are *not* loaded via the autoloader.** It's a common mistake to think that controller class definitions are subject to the same codepool load order as all of the other class types

So, the reason your code is not executing is because you have not implemented a proper controller rewrite mechanism. You'll need to add a directory under the `customer` frontname and create a proper class definition (and manually include the original `AccountController`); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9350848/833795 for an exact implementation.

Note that there is an intended API (classical sense) for this (ref customer attribute `used_in_forms` and related values; e.g. [`vat_id`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.0-1.6.2.0.php#L89)).

Comment: It's been so long since I've worked on this so I can't remember how I managed it, but I'm going ahead and accepting your answer anyway.

Comment: It's okay, it's the right answer :-)